# sed headaches: inserting lines upon singular matches in file (NOT per line)

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

After over eight hours of searching, I am throwing in the towel and creating a new question for this one.  The operation is simple, but I am having the hardest time getting this to work correctly, having gone through seemingly every other solution on SO.  I need two things:

1.) To insert a line before a line in which the FIRST MATCH of `PBS` in the entire file occurs.  It should only happen once in the entire file.  For some reason, every solution I've tried has ended up duplicating the insert for every occurrence in the file; I suspect, because sed is following on a per-line basis.

So this needs to happen. Original file:

```
stuff here  
stuff here  
PBS -N  
PBS -V  
stuff here
```

becomes:

```
stuff here  
stuff here  
**inserted line**  
PBS -N  
PBS -V  
stuff here
```

2.) To append a line after a line in which the LAST MATCH of "PBS" in the entire file occurs.  Same as before: it should only happen once in the entire file.

So this needs to happen:

```
stuff here  
stuff here  
PBS -N  
PBS -V  
stuff here
```

becomes:

```
stuff here  
stuff here  
PBS -N  
PBS -V  
**inserted line**  
stuff here
```

All of the solutions I'm seeing online (and I have about twenty tabs open at this point) state that this should be relatively easy. I have no shame in declaring that sed is taking a toll on my self-esteem at this point... Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: I feel your pain. One-character commands are ... not obvious. I really only use sed for simple search and replace, or to print/remove specific lines. Anything complicated, I use another, more readable language, or here to wh*re for rep ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three methods, two using sed and one using awk.

### Using sed alone

To insert once before the first occurrence

```
$ sed ':a;$!{N;ba}; s/PBS/inserted line\nPBS/' file
stuff here
stuff here
inserted line
PBS -N
PBS -V
stuff here
```

To insert once after the last occurrence:

```
$ tac file | sed ':a;$!{N;ba}; s/PBS/inserted line\nPBS/' | tac
stuff here
stuff here
PBS -N
PBS -V
inserted line
stuff here
```

#### How it works

- `:a;$!{N;ba};`

  This reads the whole file in at once.  (*If the whole file is very large, you will want to look at one of the other methods.*)
- `s/PBS/inserted line\nPBS/`

  This performs the substitution.
- `tac`

  Normally, there would be no way to know which occurrence of PBS is the last in a file until we have read in the whole file.  `tac`, however, reverses the order of the lines.  Consequently, what was last becomes first.

### Using awk

The key advantage of awk is that it allows easy use of variables.  Here we create a flag `f` which is set to true after we reach the first occurrence of PBS:

```
$ awk '/PBS/ && !f {print "inserted line"; f=1} 1'  file
stuff here
stuff here
inserted line
PBS -N
PBS -V
stuff here
```

To insert after the last occurrence, we could use a `tac` solution as above.  For variety, this approach reads the file in twice. On the first run, it keeps track of the last line number of PBS.  On the second, it prints what needs to be printed:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{if (/PBS/)n=FNR;next} 1{print} n==FNR {print "inserted line"}'  file file
stuff here
stuff here
PBS -N
PBS -V
inserted line
stuff here
```

These awk solutions process the file one line at a time.  This helps limit memory usage if the file is very large.

### Using grep and sed

Another approach is to use `grep` to tell us the line number that we need to work on.  This inserts before the first occurrence:

```
$ sed "$(grep -n PBS file | cut -d: -f1 | head -n1)"' s/PBS/inserted line\nPBS/' file
stuff here
stuff here
inserted line
PBS -N
PBS -V
stuff here
```

This inserts after the last:

```
$ sed  "$(grep -n PBS file | cut -d: -f1 | tail -n1)"' s/.*PBS.*/&\ninserted line/' file
stuff here
stuff here
PBS -N
PBS -V
inserted line
stuff here
```

This approach does not need to read the whole file into memory at once.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered this question, but I ended up using the grep + sed solution here.  Very elegant solution, thank you John.

Answer (score 0):

@John1924 answer is the good one. In such cases, you can also do the task not in effective way, e.g.:

- print only lines before 1st PBS
- echo the line
- print only lines after (included) the 1st PBS

eg. when having the following in the `./pbsfile`

```
line 1
line 2
PBS -N first
PBS -N second
line 3
PBS -V last-1
PBS -V last
line 4
line 5
```

the above can be done for example:

```
pbsfile="./pbsfile"

(
#delete the lines after the 1st PBS
#so remains only the lines before the 1st PBS
sed  '/PBS/,$d' "$pbsfile"

#echo the needed line
echo "THIS SOULD BE INSERTED BEFORE 1st PBS"

#print only the lines after the 1st PBS
sed -n '/PBS/,$p' "$pbsfile"

)
```

produces:

```
line 1
line 2
THIS SOULD BE INSERTED BEFORE 1st PBS
PBS -N first
PBS -N second
line 3
PBS -V last-1
PBS -V last
line 4
line 5
```

Same as above, you can do for the last PBS, just reverse the file before and after the sed, e.g. the following

```
pbsfile="./pbsfile"

(
tail -r "$pbsfile" | sed -n '/PBS/,$p' | tail -r
echo "THIS SOULD BE INSERTED AFTER THE LAST PBS"
tail -r "$pbsfile" | sed  '/PBS/,$d' | tail -r
)
```

what produces

```
line 1
line 2
PBS -N first
PBS -N second
line 3
PBS -V last-1
PBS -V last
THIS SOULD BE INSERTED AFTER THE LAST PBS
line 4
line 5
```

Again, this is only for as "alternative solution" (it isn't effective).

Answer (score 0):

Another sed approach:

```
sed '/PBS/ {
  # insert the new line
  i\
inserted line
  # then loop over the rest of the file, implicitly printing each line
  :a; n; ba
}' file
```

For the *last* match, this version does not require `tac`

```
sed '
  # read the whole file into pattern space
  :a; $!{N;ba}
  # then, use greedy matching to get to the *last* PBS
  # and non-greedy matching to get to the end of that line.
  s/.*PBS[^\n]*/&\ninserted line/   
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is the wrong tool for this kind of job, it's for simple substitutions on individual lines. Just use awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR  == FNR { if (/PBS/) hits[++numHits] = NR; next }
FNR == hits[1] { print "inserted line before" }
{ print }
FNR == hits[numHits] { print "inserted line after" }

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
stuff here
stuff here
inserted line before
PBS -N
PBS -V
inserted line after
stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` that read the file only once:

```
cat file
line 1
line 2
PBS -N first
PBS -N second
line 3
PBS -V last-1
PBS -V last
line 4
line 5
```

```
awk '/PBS/ {last=NR;if (!f) {first=NR;f=1}} {a[NR]=$0} END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) {if (i==first) a[i]="new line before\n"a[i];if (i==last) a[i]=a[i]"\nnew line after";print a[i]}}' file
line 1
line 2
new line before
PBS -N first
PBS -N second
line 3
PBS -V last-1
PBS -V last
new line after
line 4
line 5
```

---

How it works:

```
awk '                                       # Start
/PBS/ {                                     # Does line contains "PBS"
    last=NR                                 # Set last to current line number
    if (!f) {                               # Is flag "f" false
        first=NR                            # Yes, set first line to current line
        f=1}}                               # and set flag "f"
    {
    a[NR]=$0}                               # Store alle line in array "a"
END {
    for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) {                   # Loop trough all lines
        if (i==first)                       # Is line number equal to first hits
            a[i]="new line before\n"a[i]    # Add data before line
        if (i==last)                        # Is line number equal to last hits
            a[i]=a[i]"\nnew line after"     # Add data after line
        print a[i]}}                        # Print the line
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

To get sed doing it properly you have to bypass its per-line operation and then reinstitute it with raw regexes. It's not hard, just a little bit fiddly.

```
sed -E 'H;$!d;g
        s/\n[^\n]*PBS/\ninsert before first PBS-containing line&/
        s/.*PBS[^\n]*/&\ninsert after last PBS-containing line/;
        s/.//
'
```

The `H;$!d;g` slurps the whole file to the hold buffer with an extra newline at the front (`H` is append the current line to the hold buffer with a `\n` in front, `$!d` is delete if this wasn't the last line; `g` (and what follows it) only runs on the last line and retrieves the hold buffer.

So the `s/\n[^\n]*PBS` will find the newline preceding the first PBS since there's always a newline before each line, the `s/.*PBS[^\n]*/` will find the last PBS and everything up to any following newline, and the `s/.//` strips the artificial newline we stuck in there to make the first-occurrence search work.

Note that you can make the 1st-occurrence insertion work for arbitrary *n* by just appending it to the search, `s/\n[^\n]*PBS/\netc&/4` for the fourth.